# Node.js get image from web and encode with base64

Tags: node.js, encoding, express, base64

I'm trying to fetch an image from the web and encode it with base64.

What I have so far is this:

```
var request = require('request');
var BufferList = require('bufferlist').BufferList;

bl = new BufferList(),

request({uri:'http://tinypng.org/images/example-shrunk-8cadd4c7.png',responseBodyStream: bl}, function (error, response, body) 
{
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
    {
        var type = response.headers["content-type"];
        var prefix = "data:" + type + ";base64,";
        var base64 = new Buffer(bl.toString(), 'binary').toString('base64');
        var data = prefix + base64;
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This seems to be pretty close to the solution, but I can't quite get it to work. It recognizes the data type and gives out this output:

```
data:image/png;base64
```

However, the bufferlist 'bl' seems to be empty.

Comment: Just a completely wild guess but I think it could be possible that the request() may be using a header indicating an agent that may be blocked by certain sites to minimize scraping.

Comment: @BrettZamir Do you think so? Blocking a request with a 200 response seems very nasty...

Comment: And may I ask: What is `require('request')`? Cannot find it in the documentation. All I know for this is http/https.

Comment: @Sebastian, yes, it is just a wild guess... But it is one of those problems which has recurred for me, so just offering it as a throwaway...

Comment: @SebastianG, if you can't find something being required in the docs, then that means it's from...? :D

Comment: @gustavohenke Sorry, I don't get it...

Answer (score 188, accepted):

BufferList is obsolete, as its functionality is now in Node core. The only tricky part here is setting request not to use any encoding:

```
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });

request.get('http://tinypng.org/images/example-shrunk-8cadd4c7.png', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great it worked, thanks!. One question though, why does request not be set to any encoding? I still get some sort of result if i skip the .defaults({ encoding: null }) part.

Comment: `encoding: null` tells request that you want a buffer, not a string. A string gives you unusably garbled data, as the whole point of base64 is to encode binary. I got the answer about encoding in my own StackOverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619980/failing-mocha-test-on-hash-of-favicon-static-image, so I'm happy to pay it forward.

Comment: Works fine on localhost but getting ECONNREFUSED in production. Any ideas?

Comment: Solution: Run production from localhost

Comment: May all Gods bless you... I knew it was an encoding problem, but I was struggling to find how to disable it on request library...

Comment: @DanKohn `new Buffer` is now deprecated. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: request is also deprecated

Answer (score 59):

If anyone encounter the same issue while using axios as the http client, the solution is to add the responseType property to the request options with the value of 'arraybuffer':

```
let image = await axios.get('http://aaa.bbb/image.png', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
let returnedB64 = Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me saved a bunch of time and frustration!

Comment: I was having a lot of issues with this and axios, turns out the response type is what makes it. Thansk a lot!

Answer (score 43):

**DISCLAIMER: NO INSTALLATION REQUIRED**

This works using built-in `http` module!

**NOTE**: I tried it in node version 6.x, also applicable to above versions.

```
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://tinypng.org/images/example-shrunk-8cadd4c7.png', (resp) => {
    resp.setEncoding('base64');
    body = "data:" + resp.headers["content-type"] + ";base64,";
    resp.on('data', (data) => { body += data});
    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(body);
        //return res.json({result: body, status: 'success'});
    });
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

I hope it helps!

Also, check more about the `http.get(...)` [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) !

Comment: This works.  I had to use both the http and https modules in my solution since most resources are https today.  Unfortunately, you'll need to check manually which module to use.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45215071/4978821.

Comment: Best answer for me!

Answer (score 23):

Another way of using node fetch, which breaks down the steps per variable:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const imageUrl = "Your URL here";
const imageUrlData = await fetch(imageUrl);
const buffer = await imageUrlData.arrayBuffer();
const stringifiedBuffer = Buffer.from(buffer).toString('base64');
const contentType = imageUrlData.headers.get('content-type');
const imageBase64 = 
`data:${contentType};base64,${stringifiedBuffer}`;
```

Comment: This was the one for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

If you know the image type, it's a one-liner with the `node-fetch` package. Might not suit everyone, but I already had `node-fetch` as a dependency, so in case others are in a similar boat:

```
await fetch(url).then(r => r.buffer()).then(buf => `data:image/${type};base64,`+buf.toString('base64'));
```

Comment: Nice and concise!

Comment: Works well! `.buffer` has been deprecated. This is the new way: `const blob = await response.arrayBuffer(); return \`data:${response.headers.get("content-type")};base64,${Buffer.from(blob).toString("base64")}\`;`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using axios then you can follow below steps

```
var axios = require('axios');
const url ="put your url here";
const image = await axios.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
const raw = Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64');
const base64Image = "data:" + image.headers["content-type"] + ";base64,"+raw;
```

you can check with decode base64.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [base64-stream](https://github.com/mazira/base64-stream) Node.js module, which is a streaming Base64 encoder / decoder. The benefit of this method is that you can convert the image without having to buffer the whole thing into memory, and without using the request module.

```
var http = require('http');
var base64encode = require('base64-stream').Encode;

http.get('http://tinypng.org/images/example-shrunk-8cadd4c7.png', function(res) {
    if (res.statusCode === 200)
        res.pipe(base64encode()).pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I use for load and encode image into base64 string [node-base64-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-base64-image)  npm module.

Download and encode an image:

```
var base64 = require('node-base64-image');

var options = {string: true};
base64.base64encoder('www.someurl.com/image.jpg', options, function (err, image) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(image);
});
```

Encode a local image:

```
var base64 = require('node-base64-image');

var path = __dirname + '/../test.jpg',
options = {localFile: true, string: true};
base64.base64encoder(path, options, function (err, image) {  
    if (err) { console.log(err); }  
    console.log(image);  
});
```

Comment: base64.encode(<URL>, <OPTIONS>, <CALLBACK>)
api reference: https://github.com/riyadhalnur/node-base64-image/blob/HEAD/docs/docs.md

Comment: ECONNREFUSED error when trying this npm package. can see same issue opened in GitHub but no resolutions given

Answer (score 2):

Oneliner:

```
Buffer.from(
    (
      await axios.get(image, {
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
    })
  ).data,
  "utf-8"
).toString("base64")
```

Answer (score 2):

Old post but could help someone.
On the basis of Dmytro response that help me.

```
const base64FromUrl = async (url: string) => {
  try {
    return Buffer.from((await axios.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer", })).data, "utf-8").toString("base64")
  } catch (error) {
    return ""
  }
}
```

I've just add error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [image-to-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64) Node.js module

The benefit of using this module is that you convert your image hassle-free

```js
const imageToBase64 = require('image-to-base64');

const imageLink = 'Your image link'
imageToBase64(imageLink);
.then((response) => {
    const base64Image = `data:image/png;base64,${response}`
    console.log(base64Image);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```