# how to load an image from url into buffer in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to nodejs and am trying to set up a server where i get the exif information from an image. My images are on S3 so I want to be able to just pass in the s3 url as a parameter and grab the image from it.

I am u using the ExifImage project below to get the exif info and according to their documentation:

"Instead of providing a filename of an image in your filesystem you can also pass a Buffer to ExifImage."

How can I load an image to the buffer in node from a url so I can pass it to the ExifImage function

ExifImage Project:
https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-exif

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try setting up request like this:

```
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
request.get(s3Url, function (err, res, body) {
      //process exif here
});
```

Setting `encoding` to `null` will cause request to output a buffer instead of a string.

Comment: thanks that worked!
Do I need to be concerned about loading too many images this way, or are they automatically deleted?

Comment: The V8 Javascript engine will garbage collect unused memory, so you should be fine.

Comment: You mention it will "output" a buffer. Could you describe where the output is? request does not return a value.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce Here's a more complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17133012/1935918

Comment: Request is deprecated, there are others:  https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Answer (score 62):

Use the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios):

```
const response = await axios.get(url,  { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, "utf-8")
```

Comment: This should be  the accepted answer in 2021

Comment: And also in 2022.

Comment: why "utf-8"? that is a binary content

Comment: bless your soul

Answer (score 33):

```js
import fetch from "node-fetch";

let fimg = await fetch(image.src)
let fimgb = Buffer.from(await fimg.arrayBuffer())
```

Comment: worked for me, even with native node fetch https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/globals.html#fetch, but still marked as experimental 

Answer (score 21):

I was able to solve this only after reading that `encoding: null` is **required** and providing it as an parameter to request.

This will download the image from url and produce a buffer with the image data.

Using the request library -

```
const request = require('request');

let url = 'http://website.com/image.png';
request({ url, encoding: null }, (err, resp, buffer) => {
     // Use the buffer
     // buffer contains the image data
     // typeof buffer === 'object'
});
```

Note: omitting the `encoding: null` will result in an unusable string and not in a buffer. Buffer.from won't work correctly too.

This was tested with Node 8

Comment: uri is missing:
request({ uri: url, encoding: null }, (err, resp, buffer) => {

Comment: Request is deprecated:  https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Answer (score 9):

Use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library.

```
request('<s3imageurl>', function(err, response, buffer) {
    // Do something
});
```

Also, [node-image-headers](https://github.com/sujal/node-image-headers) might be of interest to you. It sounds like it takes a stream, so it might not even have to download the full image from S3 in order to process the headers.

*Updated with correct callback signature.*

Comment: i tried using the request method, but the buffer is always null. If i put in the imageurl directly in the browser it loads fine. Any idea why that may be the case?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong signature for the callback. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that uses the native `https` library.

```
import { get } from "https";

function urlToBuffer(url: string): Promise<Buffer> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data: Uint8Array[] = [];
    get(url, (res) => {
      res
        .on("data", (chunk: Uint8Array) => {
          data.push(chunk);
        })
        .on("end", () => {
          resolve(Buffer.concat(data));
        })
        .on("error", (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  });
}

const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/8k7e1Hm.png";
const imageBuffer = await urlToBuffer(imageUrl);
```

Feel free to delete the types if you're looking for javascript.

I prefer this approach because it doesn't rely on 3rd party libraries or the deprecated request library.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it that way

```
import axios from "axios";

function getFileContentById(
  download_url: string
): Promise < Buffer > {
  const response = await axios.get(download_url, {
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
  });
  return Buffer.from(response.data, "base64");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`request` is deprecated and should be avoided if possible.

Good alternatives include [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) (only for node.js) and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) (which also support browsers).

Example of `got`:

```
npm install got
```

Using the async/await syntax:

```
const got = require('got');

const url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await got(url, { responseType: 'buffer' });
        const buffer = response.body;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.body);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplest 2 line code to do this

In **node.js** there is inbuilt module called **node-fetch**.
You can use that to download image from url and use as a **buffer** then you can save that buffer in any file system like **s3-bucket** azure etc.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"

const image_url = "https://my-image-url.com";
const res = await fetch(image_url);
const resBuffer = await res.buffer();
```