# Resize and compress image from URL and upload to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sharp

I have a function that is supposed to get an image from an external URL, optimize it with sharp, and then upload the image to S3.

But it doesn't seem like I can get sharp to work for resizing and compression.

Here is my current code:

```
const got = require('got');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  credentials,
});

async function uploadFile(url) {
  // Get file
  const response = await got(url, { responseType: 'buffer' });

  // Resize, compress and convert image before upload
  const { data, info } = await sharp(response.body)
    .resize({ width: 512 })
    .jpeg({ quality: 70 })
    .toBuffer();

  console.log('data:', data);

  const uploadedFile = await s3
    .upload({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: 'filename.jpg',
      Body: data,
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    })
    .promise();

  console.log('uploadedFile:', uploadedFile);
}
```

Error I get: `Input file is missing`

The code fails when the `sharp` method is called.

The kind of output I get from response.body [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A44YO.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried `await sharp(Buffer.from(response.body))`?

Comment: I'm getting `Input buffer contains unsupported image format` when trying it on png and jpg images.

Comment: Not very familiar with the `got` library, but it seems to require the body to be resolved asynchronously, for example: `const body = await got(url).buffer()` which essentially sets responseType: buffer and resolveBodyOnly: true.

Comment: I get `got(...).buffer is not a function` when I do that, not sure why. It should work, based on this example I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63965189/10014988

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to make two changes, as follows:

```
const body = await got(url).buffer();
```

and:

```
const data = await sharp(body)
    .resize({ width: 512 })
    .jpeg({ quality: 70 })
    .toBuffer();
```

With those changes, your code works for me. I downloaded a random image from the web and uploaded it successfully to S3. Also, make sure you have up to date packages for got and sharp.

Comment: It looks like I had to force a never major version of `got` to be installed, even though I installed it quite recently.