# Using ExcelJS, how to read data from excel file using URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, exceljs

I have excel file upload in cloud. Using node js when front end pass URL i need to read data from excel file. Below is my code,

```
  var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook(); 
  workbook.xlsx.load('https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLSX_10.xlsx')
    .then(function() {
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheet);
        worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {
          console.log("Row " + rowNumber + " = " + JSON.stringify(row.values));
        });
    });
```

But I'm getting this error,

**Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html**

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed using the below code.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const jsontoxml = require("jsontoxml");

async function testAxiosXlsx(url) {
    const options = { 
        url,
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
    }
    let axiosResponse = await axios(options);
    const workbook = XLSX.read(axiosResponse.data);

    let worksheets = workbook.SheetNames.map(sheetName => {
        return { sheetName, data: XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]) };
    });

    console.log("json:\n", JSON.stringify(worksheets), "\n\n");
    console.log("xml:\n", jsontoxml(worksheets, {}));
}

testAxiosXlsx("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLSX_10.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the documentation](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#reading-xlsx).

The `load` method expects you to pass a Buffer containing Excel data.

You are passing it a string, and that string contains a URL, not Excel data.

You need to [fetch the data and convert it to a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65945192/19068).