# Unable to delete Excel file after reading from the file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I have file hosted on S3 bucket from where I am fetching the Excel file using an Axios request. After that I am writing that Excel file in the local filesystem. After that I am converting that Excel file data into JSON and sending it as a response; for that I am using XLSX library.

After sending the Excel file data as a JSON response I want to delete that Excel file from local filesystem.

When I am trying to delete the file it's failing to delete as well as failed to read the file. But when file is already available then it's reading the file and sending the response also.

Below is my code:

```
const response = await axios.get(data.me_url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

        if (response) {

            const ostream = await fs.createWriteStream(`./${filename}`, 'binary');
            ostream.write(response.data);
            ostream.end();

            const file = xlsx.readFile(`./${filename}`);
            const sheetNames = file.SheetNames;
            const totalSheets = sheetNames.length;

            let parsedData = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < totalSheets; i++) {

                const tempData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[sheetNames[i]]);
                tempData.shift();
                parsedData.push(...tempData);
            }

            if (parsedData.length > 0) {
                console.log('if filename',filename);
                try {
                    fs.unlinkSync(`./${filename}`);
                  
                    console.log("Delete File successfully.");
                    return res.status(200).send({ 'data': parsedData, 'message': 'Success', 'code': 200 });
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  }
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Comment: can you show us `filename` log

Comment: filename is simply a name of a file that I have written in local system using write stream

Comment: yes but if that filename doesn't have an extension it won't delete file.

Comment: I am gettting the extension along with the filename.

Comment: But one more problem also is there when file is not available already it is failed to read the file after creating the file and if file is already there then its reading properly.

Comment: so what's the error?

Comment: Its trying to read the file even before file is created.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create file in the local machine, send the file Array Buffer directly to xlsx directly as mentioned in the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72213342/using-exceljs-how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-url)