# Using curl with node.js to download an image and convert it to base64

Tags: node.js, curl, express, base64

I need to download an image from an external server and push it to my clients dynamically.

The external server is using SSL and basic authentication.  After spending hours trying to use the 'request' and 'restler' modules, I gave up and settled for the 'curlrequest' module, which is working fine.

My issue is that the binary image data downloaded by curl does not translate into a readable base64 image. I think there may be some curl flag I am missing but am not sure.  Any help is appreciated.

```
var curl = require('curlrequest');

exports.slideImageData = function (req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  var prefix = "data:image/png;base64, ";
  var options = {
    url: config.jive.domain + 'api/core/v3/people/' + id + '/images/1/data'
    , user: config.jive.user + ':' + config.jive.pass
  };
  curl.request(options, function (err, result){
    if (err){
      console.log(err)
    } else{
      var base64Image = new Buffer(result, 'binary').toString('base64');
      base64Image = prefix + base64Image;
      res.send('<img src="' + base64Image + '"/>');
    }
  });
}
```

To add more context, here is what the image looks like in the client.  The base64 encoding has been truncated intentionally with the ellipses.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, /VBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh ... AAAABJRU5E/UJg/Q==">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer, which is a variation of dankohn's response.

```
var curl = require('curlrequest');

exports.slideImageData = function (req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  var prefix = "data:image/png;base64, ";
  var options = {
    url: config.jive.domain + 'api/core/v3/people/' + id + '/images/1/data'
    , user: config.jive.user + ':' + config.jive.pass
    , encoding: null
  };
  curl.request(options, function (err, result){
      var base64Image = new Buffer(result, 'binary').toString('base64');
      base64Image = prefix + base64Image;
      res.send('<img src="' + base64Image + '"/>');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  var options = {
    url: config.jive.domain + 'api/core/v3/people/' + id + '/images/1/data'
    , user: config.jive.user + ':' + config.jive.pass
    , RAW: 1
  };
```

That's what it takes to get the data returned to you as a Buffer instead of a String. [Node.js get image from web and encode with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124053/node-js-get-image-from-web-and-encode-with-base64/17133012#17133012) shows how to do it using request.

Comment: When I try using RAW, I get the error: Failed to initialize.  Also, when I try using encoding: null, I get the error: Unknown encoding: [object object].  https://github.com/chriso/curlrequest

Comment: Try using their example for RAW, which has slightly different syntax: https://github.com/jiangmiao/node-curl