# How to make post request using SOAP in node.js

Tags: node.js, soap

I'm using the library SOAP (https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) to make requests to a wsdl, but I'm getting the error `HTTP GET not supported`, using SOAPUI or even axios with post method seems to work

Comment: i think this link is helpful for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147372/node-js-error-protocol-https-not-supported-expected-http