# How to handle JPEG data received in HTTP res.body?

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest, jpeg

I'm using the request.js node module to make a GET request for an image. The body I get back looks like this:

```
body: 'u0014�����T���8�\u00029�\u001fZ\u0000m(\u0007�\u001d�A\u0014�9E9Oz@E8s��`8d�x�j`�<rq... etc'
```

How do I read that as a JPEG?

What I'm doing is just forwarding that content as a PUT request to another endpoint. This is working, except that the image data is no readable on the new URL (which is a CouchDB document attachment).

My PUT request looks like this:

```
request({
    url: newDocUrl + '/' + aName + "?rev=" + resRev,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: headersAttachment, //{'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}
    body: attachment
}, function(e, r, b) {
    console.log('body', b);
});
```

Questions: How do I read JPEG data from an HTTP res? What format should JPEG data be to forward an image? (i.e. base64, hex, something else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Node.js get image from web and encode with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124053/node-js-get-image-from-web-and-encode-with-base64)

I didn't know that request.js encodes URL responses. By turning it off the image was posted fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axios` and specify the `responseType` as `stream`. Then you can pipe the response data to the `createWriteStream` method of the `fs` node module.

The request should be handled like this:

```js
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: '<your API URL here>',
  responseType: 'stream'
})
  .then(function (response) {
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('filename.jpg'))
  });
```

Now the `filename.jpg` can be opened as a JPEG image.

[Axios Documentation here for this](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro)