# Downloading an Image from a URL

Tags: node.js, blob, webhooks, firebase-storage, hapi.js

I'm running a node server at a specified url for a webhook. The Webhook is a simple ”image-has-been-processed”-notification via HTTP POST containing the URL to download the image (`processedImageURL`). I want to take that image and store it in Firebase storage.

My question is, how do I download this image and convert it to a blob or something that can be successfully uploaded to Firebase?

Here is my code. I'm using the Hapi framework btw. Thanks!

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: 'https://snapshelf-aa1b5.firebaseapp.com/pixelz',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

      // Get payload

      const payload = request.payload;

      reply('success');

      // How do I convert processedImageURL into blob? Below code won't work obviously

      const imageURL = payload.processedImageURL;

      // Store image in Firebase

      storageRef.put(imageURL).then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
      })

      // db.ref('/testImages/').push(downloadURL);
    }
});
```

Comment: useful to tag all relevant subparts of your issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955813/how-to-store-and-view-images-on-firebase - some useful information

Comment: To [download an image from a URL in Node](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=node.js+download+image+from+url), see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740659/downloading-images-with-node-js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17133012/4575054