# How to display the binary account image received from msal graph API?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am able to query the msal graph api by using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value` but once I have the response, which based on [the documentation][1] is a binary value, I am unable to actually display this in my Vue app. I have tried using createObjectURL to make a blob and setting that as the src attribute of the img element like this:

```
const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(response.data);
document.getElementById("imageElement").setAttribute("src", blobUrl);
```

but I get the error:

`TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.`

I am getting the image like this:

````
axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/$value", {
   headers: {
   Authorization: "Bearer " + "xxxxxxx" // this is the auth token
    }
})

.then(response => {
    const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(response.data);
    document.getElementById("imageElement").setAttribute("src", blobUrl);
});
```


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url)

Comment: This does remove my error but it still does not display the image. I changed the type to image/jpeg but the blog url does not diplay a valid image. Thanks for your comment tho!

Comment: We need more code. How do you fetch the photo? Why is response.data necessary?
`let blob = await client.api('/me/photo/$value').get()` should get you the blob.

Comment: response.data give the binary of the image. it gives a similar binary response to what ```https://random.imagecdn.app/500/500``` returns.

Comment: the photo is being fetched by ```axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/$value", {``` but that should not matter. I am able to get the binary from the api but I am just not sure how to display it my webpage.

Comment: @entropy283 We need the code. `URL.createObjectURL` only works with a Blob. Something is wrong in your code. Show it please :) You need something like `(response) => response.blob()`

Comment: Like I have been saying this is all the code but if you think it will help here it is:

````
axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/$value", {
   headers: {
   Authorization: "Bearer " + "xxxxxxx" // this is the auth token
    }
})

.then(response => {
 const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
 const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(response.data);
 document.getElementById("imageElement").setAttribute("src", blobUrl);
});
```

Comment: updated the question with the above code as well for better formatting

Comment: @entropy283 thanks for the code. You need to call `blob()` on the response. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
yourImg.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64, ' + Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
```

Also check the answers and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50421913/535480)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `blob()` on the response: [See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ntwkhrv6/10/)

```js
fetch("https://random.imagecdn.app/500/500").then(async response => {
  const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(await response.blob());
  document.getElementById("imageElement").setAttribute("src", blobUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When making a request for blob data with Axios, you need to let it know via [Request Configuration](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) to *expect* a blob. This is similar to needing to call `.blob()` on the response when you make a similar request using `fetch()`.

```js
axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/$value", {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer <your_auth_token>"
    },
    responseType: 'blob',
})
```

Without specifying a `responseType`, passing Axios' response value to `URL.createObjectURL()` will throw `TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed` because it's not actually a blob at all!