# azure graph api error on get profile picture in react MSAL

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm able to get the users token for my react app for the graph API but I'm getting an error on the request for

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/photo/$value
```

I'm using the scope https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read on the MSAL with this code:

```
  const GraphRequest = {
    scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"],
    account: accounts[0],
  };    
instance.acquireTokenSilent(GraphRequest).then((graphResponse) => {
      setBearerToken(graphResponse.accessToken);
```

with this token I do the get request like so:

```
  Axios.get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/photo/$value`, {
    headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${BearerToken}` },
    responseType: "blob",
  }).then((o) => {
    const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(o.data);
    setImageUrl(blobUrl);
  });
```

the problem is the return shows no error message its blank and I'm not sure what the error is it just says 401 unauthorized

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
}
```

in the azure app registry I have permissions for user profile and the user.read so not sure where else to go here without a reason for the error I get the same in postman

[image]

**Update**

changed url request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value` and still get the same issue and in post man
[image]

Comment: Remove `/users` from your query. The correct query is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value`.

Comment: same issue with changing it to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value

Answer (score 2):

> You are using **wrong** MS Graph query that might be the reason behind getting **`401 Unauthorized`** error.

The **correct query** to get profile picture of signed-in user is:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** like below:

[image]

To get **authorization code** value, I used below authorization request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
&state=12345
```

I got **`code`** successfully in address bar after signing in as **`Sri`** user, by running above request in browser like this:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **authorization code** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
code: <code_from_above>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token while running below query, I got **profile picture** of signed-in user successfully like below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked it in Portal, the profile picture of signed-in user is **same** as below:

[image]

In your case, modify your query by removing `/users` in it and use right query like below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

Comment: modified query still returns same error but I do appreciate all the information you provided

Comment: Have you tried the same in Postman? Could you refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421913/how-to-get-users-photoprofile-using-microsoft-graph-api?rq=1) for javascript code?

Comment: same issue in postman I can only assume its either my token or permissions in azure it just doesn't help that it not got no error message indicating why

Comment: Could you include postman screenshot by editing your question to get better idea?

Comment: updated with new screenshot

Comment: When you decode access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), can you see **User.Read** permission in `scp` claim?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253331/discussion-between-sridevi-and-angrymuffins).