# Handle image/jpeg response and display on UI by base64 encode in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, request, base64, httpresponse, imagejpeg

Using NodeJs request module, I made a request to the server and receive a response like that:

```
response.body = "����JFIF��C..."

response.headers["content-type"] = image/jpeg
```

I try to convert it to base64 encode with below code:

```
let imageData = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(response.body).toString('base64');
// "data:image/jpg;base64,77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAEBAAABAAEAAO...";
```

After that, set it to an  tag to display on UI like that:

```
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = response.imageData;
```

But the UI show break image like: [image]

If I go to the request URL directly, I still see the correct image.
I think there is something wrong with convert base64 method, but I don't know how to fix it.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide full image response and how you are getting that image data in response.If you provide little bit more information , would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake. Just use request with encoding null and everything works smoothly.

```
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
```

Ref: [Node.js get image from web and encode with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124053/node-js-get-image-from-web-and-encode-with-base64)

Comment: Yes... I was getting that ackward characters also... after setting `defaults({ encoding: null })` worked perfectly to transform it to a base64 image...