# How to send mail with attachment and message in JavaScript via Gmail API

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I can send a attachment,But I can't send attachment and messages

when I add message to send,it is failed.

```
  function sendMessage(message, callback)
  {

    var email =
        "To: " + $('#compose-to').val() + "\r\n" +
        "Subject: " + $('#compose-subject').val() + "\r\n" +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n' +
        "" +
        message+
        "\r\n\r\n" +
        "--foo_bar_baz\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: image/png\r\n" +
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
        "Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n" +
        file_ + "\r\n\r\n";

    var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
      'userId': 'me',
      'resource': {
        'raw': window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(email))).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
      }
    });

    return sendRequest.execute(callback);
  }
```

hope send mail with attachment and message in javascript by gmail api

Comment: Are you running this from NodeJs?

Comment: Running only by Javascript in the browser

Comment: I would suggest you follow the documentation on [sending the email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#examples) and the one on [uploading a file](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads) to add it to the email.

Comment: Thanks,I add 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed' it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer for documentation purposes.

According to the [file upload documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#multipart), it was necessary for the `Content-Type` to be changed to `multipart/mixed`. Most files will need this setting since it is how adding attachments works in the Gmail API.

Comment: Thanks. I hava another question.  If mail subject has Chinese Characters,it cant't display correctly in GMail Inbox.

Comment: @one What do you mean, are you asking if there would be a problem or are you saying there is?

Comment: The question detail here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212599/chinese-characters-included-in-subject-when-gmail-sends-mail-cant-be-displayed

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to send both text message and picture !

Firt of all  you have to follow thoses steps to create a connection [gapi](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs?hl=fr), but taht's not the subject there

In a second time you have to transform your attachment in a Base64, in my case it was a url image ([image to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124053/node-js-get-image-from-web-and-encode-with-base64))

Then you have to code this syntaxe (quite precisely) :

```
async function sendMessage1ereRelance(gmail) {
   const base64 = await imageUrlToBase64(urlToYourImage);
   const emailBody = 'Ceci est un body';
   const subject = 'Ceci est un test';
   const utf8Subject = `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(subject).toString(
       'base64'
   )}?=`;

   const messageParts = [
       'To: test@gmail.com',
       'Subject: ' + utf8Subject,
       'MIME-Version: 1.0',
       'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="mixed_boundary"',
       '',
       `--mixed_boundary`,
       'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="alt_boundary"',
       '',
       `--alt_boundary`,
       `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"`,
       `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`,
       '',
       Buffer.from(emailBody).toString('base64'),
       `--alt_boundary`,
       'Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="image.png"',
       'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"',
       'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64',
       '',
       base64,
       `--alt_boundary--`,
       `--mixed_boundary--`,
    ];
    const message = messageParts.join('\r\n');

    // The body needs to be base64url encoded.
    const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(message)
       .toString('base64')
       .replace(/\+/g, '-')
       .replace(/\//g, '_')
       .replace(/=+$/, '');

   // Send the email with the attachment
   await gmail.users.messages.send({
       userId: 'me',
       requestBody: {
           raw: encodedMessage,
      },
   });

   console.log('Email with attachment sent successfully');
}
```

Have a great day