# how to convert pdf downloaded through google drive into base 64 using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular7

Using google drive api documentation implemented the downloading part using node js. Now i have to convert that downloaded pdf into base64 . Can anyone please help me to go through this.

Comment: welcome to SO. What you have tried so far???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124053/node-js-get-image-from-web-and-encode-with-base64 this might help you.

Comment: i have downloaded the pdf from google drive now i want to convert that pdf to base64  @Subburaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of packages available for converting pdf to base64
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-to-base64

Comment: I have installed that package. Then i tried to convert my pdf it not working